# Javascript - change html element in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Dumb question, I'm sure, but I don't know the answer.

I've got a field that I populated this way

```
<div class="field">
<%f.label :client_id %>
<%= f.select :client_id,
      options_for_select(Client.all.map{ |p| [p.appointment_record, p.id]}), # your options for this select box
      include_blank: 'Select Client'
%>
```

So when I get

```
clients = $('#appointment_client_id').html()
```

it's

```
<option value="">Select Patient First, Please</option>
<option value="1">Guy, First - Programmer</option>
<option value="2">Guy, Second - Code Monkey</option>
```

What I want is to change those value tags. This list is generated dynamically.

How could I change the value tags in an .each loop so that it sticks?

Comment: Explanation is lacking in details. Need to be more specific about what you want to change and what the source is for new values. Show expected results based on your current exaample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear at all what you want to change or from what source.

Assuming you want to change `<option>` values you can use **[`val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)** to loop through collection. The arguments of the function are index and current value

Example:

```
$('#appointment_client_id').children(':gt(0)').val(function(i, currVal){
    return currVal ? currVal * 10 :'';
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0oxzwn8w/1/)**</kbd>